# Move value with the same column into one

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

everyone
I have issue with column arrangement in python dataframe. I want to move value with the same column into one.
result i want to produce like image number 2.

Thank you in advance!!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

bo = merge.filter(regex='Business Objective')
mba = merge.filter(regex='Main Business')

bo = bo.transpose().reset_index(drop=True)
mba = mba.transpose().reset_index(drop=True)

joinTogather = bo.join(bma)